# How to integrate REST API with google auth android, so that only users that are signed up on the webapp log in via their google account on android?

Tags: android, django, rest, django-rest-framework

1. I have used Django Allauth for user authentication in my django webapp(used google login).
2. I have Rest APIs for the models in my project.
3. Made Rest API for the "User" model too containing all the user info. Used Django Rest Framework for these.

How do I use these integrate REST API with google auth android, so that only users that are signed up on the webapp can only log in via their google account on android?

Please do not give vague, generic answers. Please give clear directions on what to do next. I am a beginner.